# Array sorting - sort function

Tags: c++, sorting

I have this code:

```
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    cin>>v[i];
sort(v,v+n+1);
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    cout<<v[i]<<" ";
```

I don't know why when I enter for example n=5 and the values -2 -5 0 4 3 the program outputs -2 0 3 4 0. Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: C++ uses 0-indexing.

Comment: C++ has Zero indexed arrays

Comment: You don't assign `v[0]` in your loop, but it is used in the `sort`.

Comment: did you look at your debugger and see the value of 'v'?

Comment: I knew that and I was almost sure I checked if with i starting at 0 it works, but apparently I didn't, Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Also `sort(v,v+n+1);` -->  `sort(v,v+n);`

Answer (score 0):

Indices start at 0 in c++, so you have to do the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  cin >> v[i];
sort(v, v + n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  cout << v[i] << " ";
```

Comment: I think it is better to use `std::sort(std::begin(v) ,std::end(v))` rather than `v, v+n`

Comment: Depends on the type of `v`. Anyway, `std::begin()` requires at least C++11, which might not be wanted.

Comment: C++11 is six years old, not using it is an exception which should be mentioned by author explicitly and should not be assumed.